# vb.net - richtextbox: Bold text between <b> strings

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I have a RichTextBox (a chat). I want to bold the names. How to do it?

for example the richtextbox:

```
<b>Name1</b>: Hello!
<b>Name2</b>: Hi!
<b>Name3</b>: Hey!
```

How can I change the names to bold and remove the  strings?

**Name1**: Hello!

**Name2**: Hi!

**Name2**: Hey!

?

Comment: That's HTML, not rich text.  Use the SelectionStart and SelectionLength properties to select the name, assign the SelectionFont property with a font that was created with FontStyle.Bold.

Comment: Are you populating the chat yourself?...or is the data coming like that with tags already in it?

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287595(v=vs.71).aspx

You basicly need to inject the following into the string

```
richTextBox1.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi This is in \b bold\b0.}";
```